# Solidity functions return uint as hex

Tags: solidity, javascript, ethers.js

Using Ethers JS library in javascript code.
When calling a solididy function that returns an Uint type, its returning an object with the uint in hex format.

SOLIDITY function

```
function totalRecords() public view returns (uint256){
    return Records.length;
}
```

ETHERS JS call

```
CONTRACT.totalRecords().then( _num => { console.log("TOTAL_RECORDS " + _num); });
```

REPONSE

```
Object { _hex: "0x0a", _isBigNumber: true }
​
_hex: "0x0a"
​
_isBigNumber: true
```

Answer (score 1):

I get the uint of the returned object as hex with `ethers.utils.arrayify() function`

```
CONTRACT.totalRecords().then( _num => { 
   console.log("TOTAL_RECORDS ");  
   console.log( ethers.utils.arrayify( _num._hex )[0] ); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `_hex` is an internal value, and [`toString()` should be available](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/bignumber/#BigNumber--BigNumber--methods--conversion) for you.

```
-CONTRACT.totalRecords().then( _num => { console.log("TOTAL_RECORDS " + _num); });
+CONTRACT.totalRecords().then( _num => { console.log("TOTAL_RECORDS " + _num.toString()); });
```